# How does RequireJS handle modules?

Tags: java, backbone.js, coffeescript, requirejs, playframework-2.2

My understanding of RequireJS was that if you required module B from module A, and then module B required module C, module C would be able to access module A. Is this correct?

If not, how would I get module C to use A?

Here's my problem:
I have a Backbone model Accounts, a coffee file called Core, and the cmsmain file used by the require script tag in my HTML.
`cmsmain.coffee`

```
requirejs.config
    baseUrl: 'assets/javascripts/cms'
    paths: 
        jquery: '../lib/jquery'
        backbone: '../lib/backbone'
        underscore: '../lib/underscore'
        AccountModel: 'model/account'


require ['core', 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], (Core, $, _, Backbone) ->
    Core.Start()
```

core.coffee:

```
define () ->
    # Declare the app namespace
    Core = window.Core =
        Classes:
            Models: {}
            Collections: {}
            Controllers: {}
            Views: {}
        Rendered:
            Models: {}
            Collections: {}
            Controllers: {}
            Views: {}
        Templates: {}
        Routes: {}
        Start: ->
            alert("Started")

    return Core
```

`model/account.coffee`

```
# Account Model
define () -> 
    class Core.Classes.Models.Account extends Backbone.Model

        initialize: ->

        login: (username, password) ->
```

Everything worked fine until i required the Account model, then I got:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Core is not defined
```

Even after I required Core in the accounts model i got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Classes' of undefined
```

Both errors were generated by the account model

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the value returned by the RequireJS dependency (CoffeeScript approximative...):

```
define ['core'], (Core) -> 
    class Core.Classes.Models.Account extends Backbone.Model

        initialize: ->

        login: (username, password) ->
```

Otherwise, RequireJS won't wait for `Core` to be loaded before trying to access the `Classes` attribute.

See for example https://github.com/davidsulc/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/edit/edit_controller.js

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Classes' of undefined` I already tried this, i put it in my question...

Comment: Another possibility is that you have a circular dependency. Does `Core`depend on anything?

Comment: No, it doesn't. All it does is declare the global namespace for my app